# Calculating inverses in probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am asked to find the number of proposals to submit such that at least one proposal is approved with at least $99\%$ probability.

I have found that the probability of at least one proposal being approved when three proposals are submitted is $0.957125$. It is also provided to me in the question that any one proposal has an approval probability of $0.65$.

Now, what I tried to do to find the minimum number of proposals to achieve at least a $99\%$ success, is by using the standard normal distribution.

I did: $P(Z\ge1)\ge0.99$, $P(Z=0)=0.01$ and $\operatorname{norminv}(0.01, 0, 1) = -2.3263$.

I adopted the standard normal as I was not given any mean or standard deviation in the question. I then realised that calculating the norminv led me nowhere, because I had no mean or standard deviation.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: so, you want to find the number of proposals such that the probability of no proposals being accepted is less than or equal to 1 percent. This is just $(0.65)^n\leq0.01$

Comment: Hi. I just have one source of confusion, why is it 0.65 as opposed to 1-0.65? I plugged in values into the binomial pdf, and I have the same equation as above, except I have 0.35^n. Thank you for your help.